# Stopping graticule labels from overlapping edges using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, layouts, grids-graticules

I am using ArcMap.

Every time I make a layout I find myself having to convert the graticule to graphics and then delete the edge coordinate labels for one of the axis (since they overlap with each other automatically).

Is there a way to prevent this overlapping from happening automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could manually change the graduations such that they were spaced far apart from overlapping.
2. You could just turn off labels for one or more axis from the Data Frame Properties - Grids - Properties dialog.
3. From that same dialog your could offset the labels to prevent overlap.
4. You might try changing the label orientation as well (also in the grid label properties)
5. Consider reducing the label font size (also in the grid label properties)

[image]

Comment: If I switch off the labels from one of the sides (the one that overlaps) it seems to do the trick. I also noticed that a neat trick is to make a noticeable zoom to the layout, and then converting the graticule to graphics (I noticed when I zoomed into the labels that overlapped, one of them dissapeared and the overlap was ressolved, but when I zoomed out it didn't show up, this led to the idea and it also works!), this way I just convert to graphics at the end with a big zoom and I can keep all of my graticle axis labels, thank you for the response